# Getting wrong image index

Tags: android, typedarray

array.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer-array name="animal">
        <item>@drawable/animal1</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal10</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal100</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal101</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal102</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal103</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal104</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal105</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal106</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal107</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal108</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal109</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal11</item>
        <item>@drawable/animal110</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.class

Here I'm getting value of animal array into imgs (TypedArray)

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.animal);
```

And now retrieving Resource Id and storing into ArrayList of Integers like this

```
ArrayList<Integer> myImageList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<mystikers.length(); i++){
    myImageList.add(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
}
```

Now when set image, it gives wrong image, and same image multiple time as well

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(myImageList.get(5))
                    .override(150, 150)
                    .into(imageView);
```

And if I use recycle() to recycle images (TypedArray)

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.animal);
ArrayList<Integer> myImageList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<imgs.length(); i++){
        myImageList.add(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
    }
imgs.recycle();
```

It shows this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot make calls to a recycled instance!
```

My gridview adapter where I'm getting error

```
public class StikAdpter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    int size=0;
    ArrayList<Integer> img_List = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> myImageList22 = new ArrayList<>();

    public StikAdpter(Context c,ArrayList<Integer> img_Detail_List,TypedArray mystikerishere){
        mContext= c;
        img_List=img_Detail_List;
        size = img_List.size();
        Log.v("count",String.valueOf(size));
        for(int i=0; i<mystikerishere.length(); i++){
            myImageList22.add(mystikerishere.getResourceId(i, -1));
            Log.v("allimages",img_List.get(i)+"");
        }
        mystikerishere.recycle();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView1;

        if (convertView == null) {
            gridView1 = new View(mContext);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_items, null);

            // set image based on selected text
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView1
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(myImageList22.get(position))
                    .override(150, 150)
                    .into(imageView);
            gridView1.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.AUTO_FIT, 200));
        }else {
            gridView1 = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your method where you are getting this error.

Comment: i added my adpter code where i'm getting error if i use mystikerishere.recycle();

Comment: and if i remove mystikerishere.recycle(); i'm getting wrong image and multiple images

Comment: i mean same image repeat multiple time in my gridview

Comment: I don't know why did you mess up the code! You are not using holder pattern, The way you inflated grid? Kindly follow some good blog.

Comment: will you please point any example of holder pattern i'm new to android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code, compare it with your existing code and ask me if you will getting confused.

```
public class StikAdpter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    ArrayList<Integer> myImageList22 = new ArrayList<>();

    public StikAdpter(Context c, ArrayList<Integer> img_Detail_List, TypedArray mystikerishere) {
        mContext = c;
        for (int i = 0; i < mystikerishere.length(); i++) {
            myImageList22.add(mystikerishere.getResourceId(i, -1));
        }
        mystikerishere.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myImageList22.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return myImageList22.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView1;
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            gridView1 = new View(mContext);
            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_items, null);
            imageView = (ImageView) gridView1
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            // set image based on selected text
            gridView1.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.AUTO_FIT, 200));
        } else {
            gridView1 = (View) convertView;
        }


        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(myImageList22.get(position))
                .override(150, 150)
                .into(imageView);

        return gridView1;
    }
}
```